# Is there any way to disply DIsplayR charts in Rstudio?

Tags: r

Like the title
says, is there any way how to display plots created in DisplyR.com in RStudio? I installed all libraries using git and it can not find objects, am I doing sometinh wrong or is it simply not possible? Im R beginner. Here is the code:

```
# VERSION 1.0.5
library(flipTables)
library(flipChartBasics)
library(flipChart)
library(flipAnalysisOfVariance)

# Set up stuff for template colors etc
# Brand colors should work for both column bars and arrows

cutoffs <- NULL
if (formOutput == "Table of Differences")
{
    if (!exists("formNumLevels"))
        formNumLevels <- 1

    cutoffs <- rep(NA, formNumLevels)
    colors.ub <- rep(NA, formNumLevels)
    colors.lb <- rep(NA, formNumLevels)
    colors.ub.border <- rep(NA, formNumLevels)
    colors.lb.border <- rep(NA, formNumLevels)
    for (i in 1:formNumLevels)
    {
        cutoffs[i] <- get0(paste0("formCondCutoff", i), ifnotfound = NA)
        colors.ub[i] <- get0(paste0("formCondShadeUB", i), ifnotfound = NA)
        colors.lb[i] <- get0(paste0("formCondShadeLB", i), ifnotfound = NA)
        colors.lb.border[i] <- get0(paste0("formCondShadeLBBorder", i), ifnotfound = NA)
        colors.ub.border[i] <- get0(paste0("formCondShadeUBBorder", i), ifnotfound = NA)
    }
}

# Determine default number of decimals to show
dn <- dimnames(formTable1)
number.type <- dn[[length(dn)]][1]
if (isTRUE(grepl("%", number.type)))
    number.type <- "Percent"
default.digits <- QAppearance$Number$DecimalPlaces[[number.type]]
if (is.null(default.digits))
    default.digits <- QAppearance$Number$DecimalPlaces[["None"]]
.ifNull <- function(a, b) if (is.null(a)) return(b) else return(a)

# Note that using the default proportion test "Non-parametric" sets QSetting$Assumptions to "ChiSquare" 
stat.assumptions <- QSettings$StatisticalAssumptions
if (is.null(stat.assumptions))
    stat.assumptions <- list(ProportionTest = "ChiSquare", ProportionBessel = FALSE, 
    MeansTest = "tTest", MeansBessel = TRUE, DesignEffectConstance = 1)
print(stat.assumptions)

if (formOutput == "Table of Differences" || !is.null(formTable2))
    table.of.diffs <- TableOfDifferences(formTable1, formTable2,
                  output = if (formOutput == "Stacked Column Chart with Statistical Significance") "qtable" else "widget",
                  proportions.test = stat.assumptions$ProportionTest,
                  proportions.bessel = stat.assumptions$ProportionBessel,
                  means.test = stat.assumptions$MeansTest,
                  means.bessel = stat.assumptions$MeanBessel,
                  design.effect.constant = stat.assumptions$DesignEffectConstant,
                  show = formShowVal,
                  cond.shade = formCondShadeType,
                  cond.shade.cutoffs = cutoffs,
                  cond.shade.ub.colors = colors.ub,
                  cond.shade.lb.colors = colors.lb,
                  cond.shade.ub.bordercolors = colors.ub.border,
                  cond.shade.lb.bordercolors = colors.lb.border,
                  cond.box.radius = get0("formCondBoxRadius"),
                  cond.box.borderwidth = get0("formCondBoxWidth"),
                  cond.box.padding.top = get0("formCondBoxPaddingTop"),
                  cond.box.padding.bottom = get0("formCondBoxPaddingBottom"),
                  cond.box.padding.left = get0("formCondBoxPaddingLeft"),
                  cond.box.padding.right = get0("formCondBoxPaddingRight"),
                  cell.fill = formCellFill,
                  font.color = formFontColor,
                  font.size = formFontSize,
                  font.unit = formFontUnits,
                  font.family = formFontFamily,
                  legend.show = formLegendShow,
                  legend.font.family = get0("formLegendFontFamily"),
                  legend.font.color = get0("formLegendFontColor"),
                  legend.font.size = get0("formLegendFontSize"),
                  format.statistic.decimals = .ifNull(get0("formPStatDecimals"), default.digits),
                  format.statistic.prefix = get0("formPStatPrefix"),
                  format.statistic.suffix = get0("formPStatSuffix"),
                  format.statistic.font.family = get0("formPStatFontFamily"),
                  format.statistic.font.color = get0("formPStatFontColor"),
                  format.statistic.font.autocolor = get0("formPStatFontAutocolor"),
                  format.statistic.font.size = get0("formPStatFontSize"),
                  format.difference.sign = get0("formDiffSign"),
                  format.difference.decimals = .ifNull(get0("formDiffDecimals"), default.digits),
                  format.difference.prefix = get0("formDiffPrefix"),
                  format.difference.suffix = get0("formDiffSuffix"),
                  format.difference.font.family = get0("formDiffFontFamily"),
                  format.difference.font.color = get0("formDiffFontColor"),
                  format.difference.font.autocolor = get0("formDiffFontAutocolor"),
                  format.difference.font.size = get0("formDiffFontSize"),
                  show.row.header = formRowHeadersShow,
                  row.header.fill = get0("formRowHeadFill"),
                  row.header.align.horizontal = get0("formRowHeadersAlignHoriz"),
                  row.header.pad = get0("formRowHeadersPad", ifnotfound = 0),
                  row.header.font.family = get0("formRowHeadersFontFamily"),
                  row.header.font.color = get0("formRowHeadersFontColor"),
                  row.header.font.size = get0("formRowHeadersFontSize"),
                  row.header.font.weight = get0("formRowHeadersFontWeight"), 
                  show.col.header = formColumnHeadersShow,
                  col.header.fill = get0("formColHeadFill"), 
                  col.header.font.family = get0("formColumnHeadersFontFamily"),
                  col.header.font.color = get0("formColumnHeadersFontColor"),
                  col.header.font.size = get0("formColumnHeadersFontSize"),
                  col.header.font.weight = get0("formColumnHeadersFontWeight"),
                  col.widths = formColumnWidths,
                  corner.fill = get0("formCornerFill"),
                  row.height = get0("formRowHeight"),
                  border.color = formBorderColor,
                  border.width = formBorderWidth,
                  col.header.border.width = if (isTRUE(get0("formColumnHeadersBorder"))) formBorderWidth else 0,
                  row.header.border.width = if (isTRUE(get0("formRowHeadersBorder"))) formBorderWidth else 0,
                  border.collapse = formBorderCollapse,
                  border.row.gap = get0("formBorderGapRows"),
                  border.column.gap = get0("formBorderGapColumns"),
                  row.names.to.remove = if (formOutput == "Table of Differences") formIgnoreRows else NULL,
                  column.names.to.remove = if (formOutput == "Table of Differences") formIgnoreColumns else NULL)

if (formOutput == "Stacked Column Chart with Statistical Significance")
{
    dat <- if (is.null(formTable2)) formTable1 else table.of.diffs
    if (get0("formHidePercent", ifnotfound=FALSE))
    {
        dlen <- length(dimnames(dat))
        pstat <- dimnames(dat)[[dlen]][1]
        if (grepl("%", pstat))
            dimnames(dat)[[dlen]][1] <- gsub("%", "Percent", pstat)
    }

    # Set defaults if no template
    template <- get0("formTemplate")
    if (is.null(template))
    {
        template <- list(colors = QSettings$ColorPalette, global.font = list(family = "Arial", 
        color = "#2C2C2C", size = 7.5, units = "pt"), fonts = list(
        `Data labels` = list(family = "Arial", color = "#2C2C2C", size = 7.5), 
        Legend = list(family = "Arial", color = "#2C2C2C", size = 7.5), 
        Title = list(family = "Arial", color = "#2C2C2C", size = 12), 
        Subtitle = list(family = "Arial", color = "#2C2C2C", size = 9), 
        Footer = list(family = "Arial", color = "#2C2C2C", size = 6), 
        `Categories axis title` = list(family = "Arial", color = "#2C2C2C", size = 9), 
        `Categories axis tick labels` = list(family = "Arial", color = "#2C2C2C", size = 7.5), 
        `Values axis title` = list(family = "Arial", color = "#2C2C2C", size = 9), 
        `Values axis tick labels` = list(family = "Arial", color = "#2C2C2C", size = 7.5), 
        `Panel title` = list(family = "Arial", color = "#2C2C2C", size = 9), 
        `Hover text` = list(family = "Arial", color = "#2C2C2C", size = 8.625)))
    }

    data.statistic <- ""
    if (!is.null(attr(dat, "statistic"))) {
        data.statistic <- attr(dat, "statistic")
    } else if (is.array(dat) && !is.null(attr(dat, "questions"))) {
        dn <- dim(dat)
        data.statistic <- dimnames(dat)[[length(dn)]][1]
    }
    data.is.percentage <- grepl("%", data.statistic, fixed = TRUE)
    pn <- PrepareNumbers(categories.format.list = list(get0("formCategoriesNumberType"), get0("formCategoriesDateType"), get0("formCategoriesNumberCustom"), get0("formCategoriesSeparateThousands"), get0("formCategoriesDecimals")), values.format.list = list(get0("formValuesNumberType"), get0("formValuesDateType"), get0("formValuesNumberCustom"), get0("formValuesSeparateThousands"), get0("formValuesDecimals")), hover.format.list = list(get0("formHoverNumberType"), get0("formHoverDateType"), get0("formHoverNumberCustom"), get0("formHoverSeparateThousands"), .ifNull(get0("formHoverDecimals"), default.digits)), data.labels.format.list = list(get0("formDataLabelNumberType"), get0("formDataLabelDateType"), get0("formDataLabelCustom"), get0("formDataLabelSeparateThousands"), .ifNull(get0("formDataLabelDecimals"), default.digits)), as.percentages = data.is.percentage)
   
    # Set up color vectors
    dat2 <- ConvertQTableToArray(dat)
    dat2 <- RemoveRowsAndOrColumns(dat2, formIgnoreRows, formIgnoreColumns)
    if (formTranspose)
        dat2 <- aperm(dat2, c(2, 1, 3))
    if (formColumnsReverse)
        dat2 <- dat2[,NCOL(dat2):1,,drop = FALSE]

    custom.palette <- get0("formCustomPalette")
    if (exists("formPalette"))
    {
        if (formPalette == "Custom palette (R output)")
        {
            custom.palette <- get0("formCustomPaletteROutput")
        }
        if (formPalette == "Custom palette (color pickers)")
        {
            custom.palette <- rep(NA, 12)
            for (i in 1:12)
                custom.palette[i] <- get0(paste0("formCustomPalette", i))
        }
    }
    series.colors <- GetVectorOfColors(template, dat2, NULL, "Column",
        palette = get0("formPalette"), palette.custom.color = get0("formCustomColor"), 
        palette.custom.gradient.start = get0("formCustomGradientStart"),
        palette.custom.gradient.end = get0("formCustomGradientEnd"), 
        palette.custom.palette = custom.palette) 
    arrow.colors <- if (exists("formAnnotArrowUpColor")) c(formAnnotArrowUpColor, formAnnotArrowDownColor) else  GetVectorOfColors(template, dat,
        NULL, "Column", palette = get0("formAnnotArrowPalette"), 
        palette.custom.color = get0("formAnnotArrowCustomColor"), 
        palette.custom.gradient.start = get0("formAnnotArrowCustomGradientStart"), 
        palette.custom.gradient.end = get0("formAnnotArrowCustomGradientEnd"), 
        palette.custom.palette = get0("formAnnotArrowCustomPalette"))

    chart.with.annot <- CChart("StackedColumnWithStatisticalSignificance", 
        x = dat,
        num.categories.below.axis = formNumCatBelowAxis,
        transpose = formTranspose,
        reverse.series.order = formColumnsReverse,
        row.names.to.remove = formIgnoreRows,
        column.names.to.remove = formIgnoreColumns,
        colors = series.colors,
        global.font.family = get0("formFontFamily", ifnotfound=template$global.font$family),
        global.font.color = get0("formFontColor", ifnotfound=template$global.font$color),
        annot.footer.show = get0("formAnnotFooterShow", ifnotfound=TRUE),
        annot.arrow.size = get0("formAnnotArrowSize"),
        annot.arrow.colors = arrow.colors,
        annot.arrow.offset = get0("formAnnotArrowOffset"),
        annot.alpha = 0.05, # This should reflect table - use QSettings?
        annot.legend.sep = switch(get0("formAnnotLegendSep", ifnotfound=NA), "Centered dot" = " &#183; ", "New line" = "<br>", Space = "&nbsp;", "!"),
        annot.differences.show = get0("formDiffLabelShow", ifnotfound = FALSE),
        append.annot.differences.to.datalabel = get0("formDiffAppendToDataLabel", ifnotfound = FALSE),
        annot.differences.decimals = .ifNull(get0("formDiffDecimals"), default.digits),
        annot.differences.sign.show = get0("formDiffSign", ifnotfound = TRUE),
        annot.differences.prefix = get0("formDiffPrefix"),
        annot.differences.suffix = get0("formDiffSuffix"), 
        annot.differences.font.size = get0("formDiffFontSize", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Data labels`$size),
        annot.differences.font.family = get0("formDiffFontFamily", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Data labels`$family),
        annot.differences.font.color = get0("formDiffFontColor", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Data labels`$color),
        annot.differences.offset = get0("formDiffOffset"),
        column.totals.above.show = get0("formShowTotalsAbove", ifnotfound = FALSE),
        column.totals.above.font.size = get0("formTotalsAboveFontSize", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Data labels`$size),
        column.totals.above.font.family = get0("formTotalsAboveFontFamily", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Data labels`$family),
        column.totals.above.font.color = get0("formTotalsAboveFontColor", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Data labels`$color),
        column.totals.below.show = get0("formShowTotalsBelow", ifnotfound = FALSE),
        column.totals.below.font.size = get0("formTotalsBelowFontSize", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Data labels`$size),
        column.totals.below.font.family = get0("formTotalsBelowFontFamily", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Data labels`$family),
        column.totals.below.font.color = get0("formTotalsBelowFontColor", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Data labels`$color),
        bar.gap = formBarGap,
        # Chart: DATA LABELS
        data.label.show = get0("formDataLabelShow", ifnotfound = FALSE),
        data.label.threshold = get0("formDataLabelThreshold"),
        data.label.centered = get0("formDataLabelCenter", ifnotfound = TRUE),
        data.label.format = pn$data.labels.number.format,
        data.label.font.size = get0("formDataLabelFontSize", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Data labels`$size),
        data.label.font.family = get0("formDataLabelFontFamily", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Data labels`$family),
        data.label.font.color = get0("formDataLabelFontColor", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Data labels`$color),
        data.label.font.autocolor = exists("formDataLabelFontColorOptions") && formDataLabelFontColorOptions == "Automatically",
        data.label.prefix = get0("formPrefix", ifnotfound=""),
        data.label.suffix = get0("formSuffix", ifnotfound=""),
        #Chart: GRIDLINES
        grid.show = get0("formShowGrid", ifnotfound=TRUE),
        values.line.width = get0("formValuesLineWidth", ifnotfound = 0),
        values.line.color = get0("formValuesLineColor", ifnotfound = "#000000"),
        values.zero = sum(get0("formValuesZeroLineWidth")) > 0,
        values.zero.line.width = get0("formValuesZeroLineWidth", ifnotfound = 0),
        values.zero.line.color = get0("formValuesZeroLineColor", ifnotfound = "#000000"),
        values.grid.width = get0("formValuesGridWidth", ifnotfound = 0),
        values.grid.color = get0("formValuesGridColor", ifnotfound = "#E1E1E1"),
        categories.line.width = get0("formCategoriesLineWidth", ifnotfound = 0),
        categories.line.color = get0("formCategoriesLineColor", ifnotfound = "#000000"),
        categories.grid.width = get0("formCategoriesGridWidth", ifnotfound = 0),
        categories.grid.color = get0("formCategoriesGridColor", ifnotfound = "#E1E1E1"),
        # Chart: LEGEND
        legend.show = get0("formLegendShow", ifnotfound = FALSE),
        legend.orientation = get0("formLegendOrientation", ifnotfound = "Vertical"),
        legend.title = get0("formLegendTitle"),
        legend.font.family = get0("formLegendFontFamily", ifnotfound = template$fonts$Legend$family),
        legend.font.color = get0("formLegendFontColor", ifnotfound = template$fonts$Legend$color),
        legend.font.size = get0("formLegendFontSize", ifnotfound = template$fonts$Legend$size),
        legend.x.position = get0("formLegendXPos"),
        legend.y.position = get0("formLegendYPos"),
        # Chart: TITLE
        title = paste0("", if (sum(nchar(get0("formTitle"))) > 0) formTitle else ""),
        title.font.family = get0("formTitleFontFamily", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Title`$family),
        title.font.color = get0("formTitleFontColor", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Title`$color),
        title.font.size = get0("formTitleFontSize", ifnotfound = sum(template$fonts$`Title`$size)),
        subtitle = get0("formSubtitle", ifnotfound=""),
        subtitle.font.family = get0("formSubtitleFontFamily", ifnotfound = template$fonts$Subtitle$family),
        subtitle.font.color = get0("formSubtitleFontColor", ifnotfound = template$fonts$Subtitle$color),
        subtitle.font.size = get0("formSubtitleFontSize", ifnotfound = template$fonts$Subtitle$size),
        footer = paste0("", if (sum(nchar(get0("formFooter"))) > 0) formFooter else ""),
        footer.font.family = get0("formFooterFontFamily", ifnotfound = template$fonts$Footer$family),
        footer.font.color = get0("formFooterFontColor", ifnotfound = template$fonts$Footer$color),
        footer.font.size = get0("formFooterFontSize", ifnotfound = template$fonts$Footer$size),
        footer.wrap = get0("formFooterWrap", ifnotfound=FALSE),
        footer.wrap.nchar = get0("formFooterWrapNchar"),
        footer.align = tolower(get0("formFooterAlign")),
        #Chart: CATEGORIES_AXIS
        categories.bounds.minimum = get0("formCategoriesMin"), 
        categories.bounds.maximum = get0("formCategoriesMax"), 
        categories.axis.show = get0("formCategoriesAxisShow", ifnotfound=FALSE),
        categories.tick.show = get0("formCategoriesAxisShow", ifnotfound=FALSE),
        categories.tick.format = pn$categories.number.format,
        categories.tick.prefix = paste0("", get0("formCategoriesPrefix"), get0("formCategoriesCurrency")),    # currency is just another prefix
        categories.tick.suffix = get0("formCategoriesSuffix", ifnotfound=""),
        categories.tick.interval = get0("formCategoriesTickInterval", ifnotfound=0),
        categories.tick.units = get0("formCategoriesTickUnits"),
        categories.title = paste0("", if (sum(nchar(get0("formCategoriesTitle", ifnotfound = " "))) > 0) get0("formCategoriesTitle", ifnotfound = " ")), # else pd$categories.title),
        categories.title.font.family = get0("formCategoriesTitleFontFamily", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Categories axis title`$family),
        categories.title.font.color = get0("formCategoriesTitleFontColor", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Categories axis title`$color),
        categories.title.font.size = get0("formCategoriesTitleFontSize", ifnotfound = sum(template$fonts$`Categories axis title`$size)), 
        categories.tick.font.family = get0("formCategoriesTickFontFamily", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Categories axis tick labels`$family),
        categories.tick.font.color = get0("formCategoriesTickFontColor", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Categories axis tick labels`$color),
        categories.tick.font.size = get0("formCategoriesTickFontSize", ifnotfound = sum(template$fonts$`Categories axis tick labels`$size)),
        categories.tick.angle = if (!exists("formCategoriesTickAngle")) NULL else switch(get0("formCategoriesTickAngle"), Automatic=NULL, Horizontal=0, Vertical=90, Diagonal=45),
        categories.tick.label.wrap = get0("formLabelWrap", ifnotfound=FALSE),
        categories.tick.label.wrap.nchar = get0("formLabelWrapNchar", ifnotfound=100),
        #Chart: VALUES_AXIS
        values.bounds.minimum = get0("formValuesMin"), 
        values.bounds.maximum = get0("formValuesMax"), 
        values.axis.show = get0("formValuesAxisShow", ifnotfound=FALSE),
        values.tick.show = get0("formValuesAxisShow", ifnotfound=FALSE),
        values.tick.format = pn$values.number.format,
        values.tick.prefix = paste0("", get0("formValuesPrefix"), get0("formValuesCurrency")),    # currency is just another prefix
        values.tick.suffix = get0("formValuesSuffix", ifnotfound=""),
        values.title =  paste0("", if (sum(nchar(get0("formValuesTitle", ifnotfound=" "))) > 0) get0("formValuesTitle", ifnotfound = " ")),
        values.title.font.family = get0("formValuesTitleFontFamily", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Values axis title`$family),
        values.title.font.color = get0("formValuesTitleFontColor", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Values axis title`$color),
        values.title.font.size = get0("formValuesTitleFontSize", ifnotfound = sum(template$fonts$`Values axis title`$size)),
        values.number.ticks = get0("formValuesNumberTicks"),
        values.tick.font.size = get0("formValuesTickFontSize", ifnotfound = sum(template$fonts$`Values axis tick labels`$size)),
        values.tick.font.family = get0("formValuesTickFontFamily", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Values axis tick labels`$family),
        values.tick.font.color = get0("formValuesTickFontColor", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Values axis tick labels`$color),
        # Chart: HOVER
        values.hovertext.format = pn$hover.number.format,
        values.hovertext.prefix = paste0("", get0("formHoverValuesPrefix"), get0("formHoverCurrency")),    # currency is just another prefix
        values.hovertext.suffix = get0("formHoverValuesSuffix", ifnotfound = ""),
        hovertext.font.family = get0("formHoverFontFamily", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Hover text`$family),
        hovertext.font.size = get0("formHoverFontSize", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Hover text`$size),
        hovertext.font.color = if (isTRUE(get0("formHoverAutoFontColor"))) NULL else get0("formHoverFontColor", ifnotfound = template$fonts$`Hover text`$color),
        tooltip.show = get0("formHoverShow", ifnotfound = TRUE),
        # Chart: MARGINS
        margin.top = get0("formMarginTop"),
        margin.left = get0("formMarginLeft"),
        margin.bottom = get0("formMarginBottom"),
        margin.right = get0("formMarginRight"),
        margin.autoexpand = get0("formMarginAutoexpand", ifnotfound = TRUE),
        # General arguments
        font.units = get0("formFontUnits", ifnotfound = "pt"),
        background.fill.color = get0("formBgColor", ifnotfound = "transparent"),
        background.fill.opacity = get0("formBgOpacity", ifnotfound = 1.0),
        warn.if.no.match = FALSE,
        append.data = TRUE)
}
# chart.with.annot
viz <- if (formOutput == "Table of Differences") table.of.diffs else chart.with.annot
```

I tried inserting the data to DisplayR but that doesnt work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).